# Unable to delete first item in linked list

Tags: java

I saw some solutions, but I am still unable to resolve the error in my code. My `deleteFromStart` method is not removing any elements from the list. Both invocations of `ob.display()` produce the same output. Can you tell me what I am missing, or where the error is?

**LikedList:**

```
package lab5;

public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String argsp[]){

        List ob = new List();

        ob.addAtStart("y", 6);
        ob.addAtStart("w", 4);
        ob.addAtStart("z", 3);

        ob.addAtEnd("a",3);
        ob.addAtEnd("b",4);
        ob.addAtEnd("c",5);

        ob.display();

        ob.deleteFromStart();

        System.out.println("\n");
        ob.display();
    }
}
```

**List:**

```
package lab5;

public class List {

    Node head;

    public List(){
        head=null;
    }

    public List(Node e){
        head=e;
    }

    Node oldfirst=null;
    Node lasthead=null;

    public void addAtStart(String name, int age){
        Node newObject= new Node(name,age);
        newObject.next=head;

        if (oldfirst==null) {
            oldfirst = newObject;
        }
        head = newObject;
        lasthead = head;
    }

    public void display() {
        Node store = head;
        while (store != null) {
            store.display();
            store=store.next;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void addAtEnd(String name, int age){
        Node atEndValue = new Node(name, age);
        oldfirst.next = atEndValue;
        oldfirst = atEndValue;
    }

    public void deleteFromStart() {
        while (lasthead != null) {
            lasthead = lasthead.next;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }
```

**Node:**

```
package lab5;

public class Node {

    String name;
    int age;
    Node next;

    public Node(){
        name="Abc";
        age=10;
        next=null;
    }

    public Node(String name, int age ){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        next = null;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: These oldfirst and lasthead fields are wrong. You *could* keep a reference to the *last* node to make it faster to add at the end, though. deleteFromSTart must make the head change, since head is the start.

Comment: thank you @nbrooks for corrections of my question

Comment: By "not working" do you mean that `deleteFromStart` is not actually removing any elements from the list? Is the output the same when you `display` the list, both before and after calling `deleteFromStart`?

Comment: you iterate until you make your head null, this would just wipe the list (for that head). Perhaps you meant to iterate until the node's `#next` returned null?

Comment: @nbrooks yes its printing the same out put

Comment: @nbrooks i just want to remove first element from my list can you give me answer? how to write a method for it.

Comment: @Rogue Can you tell me how to delete last node from list. `public void deleteFromEnd(){
  Node prev;
  while(head!=null){
   prev=head;
   head=head.next;
  }
  prev=null;
 }`
I am using this  method. But I lost my list I tried a lot of tries but all in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** To remove the first element in a linked-list:

```
head = head.next
```

---

When you're implementing a singly-linked list, you really only need to keep a single pointer: `head` (i.e. a reference to the first node in the list. In practice, it's also useful to keep track of the last element in the list (commonly referred to as `tail`). This allows constant-time operations at the end of the list, which are useful if you're frequently adding elements at the end. So, with this basic implementation, you end up with something like this:

```
class LinkedList {
    private Node head = null;
    private Node tail = null;

    public LinkedList() {}

    public LinkedList(Node e) {
        head = e;
        tail = e;
    }
}

class Node {
    Node next = null;
    // other data
}
```

Adding and removing elements in a linked list boils to down to updating what the `head` and `tail` variables are referring to. Consider a singly-linked list with three elements, `[A, B, C]`. The values `head` and `tail` values align like this:

```
 A -> B -> C -> null
 ^         ^
 |         |
head      tail
```

If you want to insert a new element, `X`, there are two steps:

1) Tell `X.next` to refer to `A`:

```
X -> A -> B -> C -> null
     ^         ^
     |         |
    head      tail
```

2) Update `head` to refer to `X`:

```
 X -> A -> B -> C -> null
 ^              ^
 |              |
head           tail
```

You move `head` and `tail` around in similar fashion, depending on whether you're adding or removing, and whether or not the operation is at the beginning or end of the list.

Removing an element from the start (assuming that the list is not empty) is as simple as updating `head` to refer to the next element. In our example above, this would mean moving `head` to refer to `X.next`, which is `A`:

```
X -> A -> B -> C -> null
     ^         ^
     |         |
    head      tail
```

Now remember, the linked list is only directly aware of `head` and `tail`, so once you update `head` to refer to `A` there is nothing referencing `X` anywhere in your application, and it has effectively been deleted (in Java this will cause it to be garbage-collected).

Effectively what we did above was simply `head = head.next`. Again, you'll have to ensure the list isn't empty first, since `head.next` will cause a null pointer exception if the list is empty.

I'd also suggest removing `oldfirst` and `lasthead`, and updating your `add`* methods based on the theory above.

Comment: Can you tell me how to delete last node. I am still unable to delete last single node. Every time I try I lost my list.
`public void deleteFromEnd(){
  Node prev;
  while(head!=null){
   prev=head;
   head=head.next;
  }
  prev=null;
 }`

Comment: @BadarShahzadKhan That's pretty close. You're advancing until `prev` is the last element in the list, but you really want it to be the second to last element in the list. Then you can say `prev.next = null` to remove the last element (and then if you've got a `tail` reference, update that to refer to `prev`).

Comment: `public void deleteFromEnd(){
  Node start=head;
  Node prev=null;
  while(head!=null){
   prev=head;
   head=head.next;
  }
  prev.next=null;
  head=prev;
 }`
Now  I try this but it shows the last node only. (little bit work)

Comment: @BadarShahzadKhan Deleting from the end of the list should never change `head` (which is the *start* of the list). It's hard to answer a question in comments, if you've got a new problem ask it as a new question, and I or others can provide a more detailed response there.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is not a Linked List it is more of a Queue where you have rear and front pointers.
While displaying the items in the list you are using the "head" pointer where as while deleting from start you are using "lasthead". This would move the lasthead but wont assign the value to head again.

```
 public void deleteFromStart(){

    while(lasthead!=null){

        this.lasthead=lasthead.next;
    }
    head = this.lasthead;
}
```

Well i tried this code and it **delete's** all the elements from the start (I hope this is what you wanted)

For deleting first element:

```
public void deleteElementAtStart()
{
    if(lasthead != null)
    {
        this.lasthead = lasthead.next;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("List is already empty!");
    }
    head = lasthead;
}
```

Editted it.

Comment: Nope You lost the the whole list. You should dry run you will realize your fault!

Comment: One more thing there is no difference between head and lasthead.  both of them have same address. I'm just using lasthead as for my remembrence you can use head instead of lasthead.  The problem is not that the problem is I just remove first element when I call deleterFromStart method. That's it

Comment: @BadarShahzadKhan Your problem is still unclear then , you deleteFromStart method would just move the "lasthead" pointer to the next one and because of the iterations it will move the pointer to the end. If you just want to delete the first item of the list try the second code. If  i'm not at the point please explain the actual problem.

Comment: `while(lasthead.next!=null){
   System.out.println(lasthead.name);
   lasthead=lasthead.next;
   System.out.println(lasthead.name);
  }`
try to sysout you will see the address is assgining backward but it is not  showing in the queue i think we are nearer the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! I realize my mistakes I am using extra objects that's why during solution I got these two method.

```
public void deleteFromStart(){


        while(lasthead.next!=null){
            lasthead=lasthead.next;
            head=lasthead;
            break;
        }

    }
```

or

```
public void deleteFromStart(){

            while(head.next!=null){
                head=head.next;
                break;
            }

    }
```

Comment: These don't need to be `while` loops (they'll only run once anyway, since you've got an unconditional `break` as the last statement). You should use `if` instead.