# My delete method to remove a specific Node with X age value will not work

Tags: java

This is my code, please only reference the main method and delete method, other methods included just to show full program. I have heard that Java takes method arguments as pass by value, which is the issue, and the Object's properties are pass-by-reference.

So basically I could change `Node.age`, since age is a property, but I cannot make `Node` to be equal to `Node = Node.next`? I have been at this for a while, just trying to learn how to do different operations and have been stuck on this. The if-statement went through, but `headNode` did not equate to `headNode.next` like I wanted it to:

```
public class Node {
    int age;
    Node next;
    Node previous;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Node firstNode = new Node(18);
        Node t = firstNode;

        Node randomFatNode = new Node();

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i += 3) {
            Node tempNode = new Node(i + 21);
            firstNode.next = tempNode;
            tempNode.previous = firstNode;
            firstNode = tempNode;
        }

        Node tailNode = firstNode;

        firstNode = t;

        traverseForward(firstNode);
        //Prints out: Traversal Forward -> 18 -> 21 -> 24 -> 27 -> 30 -> 33 -> 36 -> 39 -> 42 -> 45 -> 48 -> null


        deleteNode(firstNode, 18); //Does not delete the first node, which has the age of 18.

        traverseForward(firstNode);
        //Prints out: Traversal Forward -> 18 -> 21 -> 24 -> 27 -> 30 -> 33 -> 36 -> 39 -> 42 -> 45 -> 48 -> null
    }

    public Node() {
        this.age = 20;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    public Node(int inputAge) {
        this.age = inputAge;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    public static void traverseForward(Node headNode) {
        System.out.print("Traversal Forward -> ");
        Node useThisForTestNode = headNode;
        while(useThisForTestNode != null) {
            System.out.print(useThisForTestNode.age + " -> ");
            useThisForTestNode = useThisForTestNode.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void deleteNode(Node headNode, int keyToDelete) {
        Node temp = headNode;
        if(temp != null && temp.age == keyToDelete)  {
            headNode = headNode.next;
            System.out.println("TEST");
            //Printed out TEST to see if if statement went through. It did, but the node in the linked list remained unchanged.
        }
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make firstNode as a class field.

Comment: This worked out, I suppose I'll include a head Node for a LinkedList class. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Precisely because Java is pass-by-value, assigning a value to the variable `headNode` doesn't affect anything outside of the scope of your `deleteNode` function. You simply overwrote the value of that variable within that scope. Passing-by-value allows you to update properties of the objects that were passed in, but not to overwrite the value stored at a particular memory location (that would be pass-by-reference).

Additionally, your linked-list is missing a crucial element: you don't actually have a list. Sure, you have a series of related nodes, but the critical piece of a linked-list is the `head`, which is a variable indicating the start of the list. Since you have a doubly-linked list, you'll typically also have a `tail` variable indicating the end of the list.

```
class LinkedList {
    private Node head = null;
    private Node tail = null;

    public LinkedList() {}

    public LinkedList(Node e) {
        head = e;
        tail = e;
    }
}
```

Removing a value from the front of the list simply amounts to re-assigning the value stored by that `head` variable:

```
public static void deleteNode(LinkedList list, int keyToDelete) {
    Node temp = list.head;

    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.age == keyToDelete) {
            // If previous is null, the element is first in the list
            // so the following element becomes the new head
            if (temp.previous == null) {
                list.head = temp.next;
            }
            else {
                // A -> B -> C
                // A -> C
                // The value after 'temp' replaces it in the list
                temp.previous.next = temp.next;
            }

            break;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

Note that the implementation above differs slightly from typical implementations, because it's a static method that you're passing the list into as a parameter.

Your `add` and `delete` methods would typically be implemented as instance methods on the `LinkedList` class (rather than as static methods on `Node`), and would require various manipulations of the `head` and `tail` variables, as further described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436176/803925).